# Using the inline Debugger of PyCharm when running a bash-Script (.sh) within the PyCharm Terminal

Tags: python, bash, shell, debugging, pycharm

I wonder if there is any possibility to use the PyCharm inline Debugger when I run a script out of the Terminal.

So I hope to do the following:

- Set breakpoint in PyCharm Editor
- Run ./script.sh -options from Terminal
- When script.sh calls a pyfile.py Python script with the breakpoint in it, it should stop there
- Giving me the possibility to use the visual debugging features of PyCharm

The above does not work right now. My only chance is to do:

- import pdb
- pdb.set_trace()

Then I could work with the pdb - but clearly I don't want to miss the great visual capabilities of the PyCharm Debugger.

I saw that PyCharm uses pydevd instead of pdb. Is there maybe a similar possibility to invoke pydevd and work with the visual debugging then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the script need to be run from bash? If not you could add a new Python run configuration (Run -> Edit configurations...). This can be run in PyCharms debug mode and will stop at breakpoints defined in the GUI. Rather than having to use set_trace, you can toggle the 'Show Python Prompt' button in console view to get a prompt so you can interact with the programme at the breakpoint.